# Converting types between databases, allowing null values in C#

Tags: c#, boolean, type-conversion

I am writing data synchronization application between sql server and firebird. In firebird is for historical reason bool provided by domain like 'Y' or 'N'. Now I want to create conversion function(s) between bool and char(1), but it should accept null values.

If input parameter will be bool or string and value from db will be null, it cause a problem right?

How can I do this?

Comment: You are right. I never saw this number before and I did not know how much unanswered questions I had. :-)

Comment: also there are "flag comment" and "Great comment" icons next to the comments others made. You can show your gratitude if you find a comment helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Nullable bool?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

You can set

```
bool? flag = false; // or null
```

later you can check [using ?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
var result = flag ?? false; // this will return false in case of null
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is tristate and your output is bistate you'll need to consider a "default". If you're just talking about handling a nullable bool in the C# part, you can use "bool?" to represent a nullable boolean (it gets boxed under the hood).